# Responsive layout issue below 560px

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a responsive website which is hosted [here](https://surijatin.github.io/covid-second-dose/). Whenever I try to reduce the resolution of the screen below 560 px or try to access the website through mobile device, the Calculate button is not shown on the screen. Can someone please help with what the issue could be here.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: The Calculate button is there but it's been set to color: white. If you hover over where it should be you will see it. Use your browser dev tools inspect facility to see exactly who/where is setting this color and change it to something visible.

Comment: @Quentin would have surely created a minimal reproducible example for this but I don't think it would be possible to do so in the first place.

Comment: @AHaworth I am aware that the button is there, but I'm not able to figure out what why is the background not coming behind that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto` on your `main-container` class.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but can you please let me know how did this solve the issue?